# iOS ARKit - move objects along path

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to move implement bouncing balls using ARKit. I want the balls coming from one end of screen bouncing and moving out of screen.

Can anyone please recommend best approach or point to sample code to implement this?

Can I use UIBezierPath to create a path and move SCNNode along the path. If yes, how can I move the node along path.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scene and a ball Node. Use force direction for ball Node and animate the ball Node with Physics. This is just an example.

```
    // Create a new scene
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "BouncingBalls.scn", inDirectory: "art.scnassets") else { return }
    sceneView.scene = scene

    // Add physics bodies
    guard let ballsNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "balls", recursively: true) else { return }
    let forceDirection = SCNVector3Make(0, 3, 0)
    for ballNode in ballsNode.childNodes {
        let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
        physicsBody.applyForce(forceDirection, asImpulse: true)
        ballNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
    }
```

Try this in View didLoad. Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks Ashman for reply. I have tried this but with this balls will bounce once at same position. They dont move on their axis or along path

Comment: You need to get the current axis of the ballsNode by `ballsNode.position.x` and move the ball.

Answer (score 0):

> The best way to get what you want is to use a **`predefined animation or dynamics`** that was made in such 3D apps as Autodesk Maya, Autodesk 3dsMax, or Maxon Cinema4D.

After producing a ball animation (or dynamics, it's up to you) you need to bake this animation (***baking*** is a process of keyframe generation for every frame instead of using interpolated curve) and export this scene as a `.dae` file format. `ARKit`/`SceneKit` supports not only `.dae` animations but also brand-new format `.usdz`.

**SceneKit API (as well as other Apple frameworks' APIs) is not designed for 3D animation**.